# Uninstallation of VB6 in Windows 7 issue

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

I am facing problems in uninstalling Visual Studio 6 Professional Edition from my laptop running Windows 7. Whenever I am trying to uninstall it, I am getting the following messages. I am posting the images:

**Window 1**

[image: Window 1]

**Window 2**

[image: Window 2]

**Window 3**

[image: Window 3]

You can easily understand I have got nothing to do with it. I could not find any possible solution to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: For the record, Revo could not help either.

Comment: Did you try right-clicking the uninstaller's shortcut and running as admin? If that doesn't help, you can always [manually uninstall](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248697) (be careful while editing the registry!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out today. There were some problems during installation of the program. Some files were missing. So I reinstalled the program, figured out which files were missing, followed the steps carefully. So this time the installation was accurate and was able to uninstall it correctly.